# Did this still from the teaser make it into The Force Awakens

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I may have blinked and missed it but I don't remember seeing this in the final film [image: light saber being handed yo Rey]

Given that

> Rey was reluctant to take it. It may not have happened.

Did I miss it or was it cut?

Comment: Weren't there several scenes that were shot differently in the trailers? E.g. I thought the first shot of Finn in the trailers had him on a sand dune taking off an unblooded helmet. I don't remember Rey saying "I'm no-one" in the actual film, and the (in)famous two-step activation of Kylo's light sabre was different in the film. Don't filmmakers for big films like this routinely film shots *specifically* to act as trailer teasers, crafting the shots deliberately to get fans talking?

Answer (score 18):

No, that shot was not in the film

**Updated w/ info from JJ Abrams**

> As for the scene from the second teaser where Maz Kanata appears to
>   hand Leia Luke's old lightsaber (pictured above), Abrams said,
>
> “That was a scene actually filmed, but we took out. At one point, Maz
>   used to continue along with the characters back to the Resistance
>   base, but we realized that she really had nothing to do there of
>   value, except to be sitting around. Lupita did film scenes on set for that sequence, but it felt it unnecessary. So we ended up leaving those things out.”

http://www.starwarsunderworld.com/2015/12/jj-abrams-discusses-deleted-scenes-from.html

Comment: I thought that too.

Comment: What really confuses me (the scene in the trailer indicated the hooded figure being Leia especially with the "my sister has it" during that trailer).....did the story especially the backstory of her char change enough for that scene to no longer be of any belonging to the film? (I mean the trailer looked like some jedi got the saber)

Comment: @Thomas likely we won't know until the Blu-Rays w/ special features are released that document the creation process. As DaaaahWhoosh says, it isn't unreasonable to also conclude this was just a cool shot J.J. wanted to frame the narrative of the trailer and keep the 'mystery box' active and interesting, yet with no plans to actually use it in the film.

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell I know some directors did things like that but I don't remember JJ doing that when he shot Star trek '1'. Neither in Star trek into darkness. Everything back then that made it into the trailers I saw in the films, Normally ppl don't change their style do they?

Comment: @Thomas - unknown - also the situation is *much* as it relates to Star Wars. One must remember that the Disney overlords / Kathleen Kennedy likely has a much sway as anyone as to what should happen for promotional materials.

Answer (score 3):

I think we can chalk this up to just another Abrams diversion. According to [this article](http://www.slashfilm.com/j-j-abrams-created-an-alternate-scene-to-preserve-the-secret-of-star-trek-into-darkness/), trailers for *Star Trek:Into Darkness* features characters specifically referring to Benedict Cumberbatch's character as 'Harrison': this was intended to make people think he wasn't playing Khan.

Abrams has this concept of a ['mystery box'](https://www.ted.com/talks/j_j_abrams_mystery_box?language=en): that is, he wants viewers of his films to be surprised, to not know everything going in. So rather than explain everything that happens in the movie in the trailers, a lot of important elements were omitted so they could be revealed later. For instance,

> Starkiller Base is not in any of the trailers.

Removing this important story element was supposed to make its reveal really cool and surprising (I think it failed miserably, but that's just me). This, on the other hand, is sort of the opposite effect, but more like the Harrison example:

> By showing us Rey taking the lightsaber, we assumed she'd do it in the film. But when she didn't we got confused, and were probably not even considering it when she *did* take the lightsaber later on.

In my case, this worked on both counts. I enjoyed these parts of the film more because they were unexpected.

Comment: FWIW - according to a podcast interview (TrekFM "Standard Orbit" - will look for the exact episode) with Robert Orci, the original story did not include Khan. Only near the end of story writing / filming (?) did they decide to make him Khan. IIRC in the interview, Orci quotes JJ as saying "why can't he be Khan?" and he pretty much made the executive decision to turn the Harrison character into Khan. All references to Harrison were left so as to enhance the 'reveal'

Answer (score 2):

As I don't want to really spoil it:

> No, that shot wasn't in the film. I expect it'll be in the director's cut later on (one's gotta hate that style element -.-). What is strange though is that Leia never has such a cloak on......and that seems like 2 female hands. So it could be from a future film already (a pre shot?) but unlikely. I Guess we will have to wait for the director's cut to be sure.

Comment: For what it's worth, Abrams is on record as saying he's not a fan of director's cuts.