# How does this photo of Kylo Ren fit into The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

In May 2015, this shot of Kylo Ren flanked by two snowtroopers was released in *Vanity Fair*:

[image]

The caption read:

> Next-generation bad guy Kylo Ren (Adam Driver) commands snowtroopers loyal to the evil First Order on the frozen plains of their secret base.

As far as I recall, there is no such scene in *The Force Awakens*. (Kylo removes his helmet exactly twice, and neither instance involves a scene like the one above.)

**What is going on in this scene, and at what point in the film would it have appeared?  Why was it excluded?  Or was it purely a promotional shot?**

Comment: Seems to me like Mr. Ren doesn't even fit in the photo.

Comment: And what are those things in the background that look like streetlights?

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's a deleted scene. Just like [this image](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111113/did-this-still-from-the-teaser-make-it-into-the-force-awakens)

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks this is photoshopped (or whatever high-tech film version is)? STs in background are all hazy, and Ren is sharp and in focus. If i had to guess, his image was layered on ice background.

Comment: @dvk That image came out before teh film way before. I remember seeing it after the first two trailers. Interstingly there that is the new snow trooper design and we also never see them in the film in that pose.

Comment: @Thomas - is there a chance we see them in that big assembly around the platform?

Comment: @dvk nope the only scene that the snow troopers were seen was inside the control room ren and hux were in. They saluted and went away (but didnt walk towards only away from the camera)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The image you have shown is not a movie still, nor is it a scene in the movie. It is, instead, an image credited to American portrait photographer [Anna-Lou "Annie" Leibovitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annie_Leibovitz) from an on-set [Vanity Fair photo-shoot](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2015/05/star-wars-the-force-awakens-vanity-fair-cover).

[image]